# azure messaging service is not receiving messages when deployed in local IIS

Tags: .net, azure, api, iis, message-queue

I have developed an app in Asp.net Web API,s. It is sending and receiving messages in deployment mode very well. but, when I deploy this app on local IIS id does not receive messages. The API is being called well but the event which is bind to receive messages on receiving messages on Azure Ques is not being fired.

Here is my code:

```
    public IHttpActionResult ReadServiceBusMessage(string outId)
    {
       
            int _outId = Convert.ToInt32(outId);
            OutletId = _outId;
            var OutletObj = (from ou in db.tblOutlets where ou.Id == _outId select ou).FirstOrDefault();
            CompanyId = OutletObj.CompanyId;
            bool? IsOMSAvailable = OutletObj.IsOMSAvailable;
            if (IsOMSAvailable != null && IsOMSAvailable == false)
            {
                return Ok("OMSAvailable is false");
            }
        string sbConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureReadPrimaryConnectionString"];
        string sbQueueName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureReadSubQueName"];
        try
        {
           
            queueClient = new QueueClient(sbConnectionString, sbQueueName);

            var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
            {
                MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
                AutoComplete = false
            };
            Console.WriteLine("I am here before register");
            queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ReceiveMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
            Console.WriteLine("I am here after register");
            //return Ok("I am here");
            //Console.Read();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            LogError(ex);
            return Ok(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            //if (param != "login")
            //{
            Console.ReadLine();

            //}
            
            queueClient.CloseAsync();
        }
        return Ok();
    }

    static async Task ReceiveMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("I am here");
        Guid Ord = new Guid();
        SendNotificationToClient(Ord);
        //GenerateException(0);
        try
        {
            
            var OutletObj = (from ou in db.tblOutlets where ou.Id == OutletId select ou).FirstOrDefault();
            CompanyId = OutletObj.CompanyId;
            bool? IsOMSAvailable = OutletObj.IsOMSAvailable;
            if (IsOMSAvailable != null && IsOMSAvailable == false)
            {
                return;
            }
            await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);

            var obj = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
            if (obj.Contains("ThirdPartyOms"))
            {
                AzureServiceBusThirdPartyMessageModel _objx = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AzureServiceBusThirdPartyMessageModel>(obj.ToString());
                AddRecievedDataFromThirdPartyToRespectiveTables(_objx);
            }
            else
            {
                AzureServiceBusMessageModel[] _obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AzureServiceBusMessageModel[]>(obj);
                AddRecievedDataToRespectiveTables(_obj);
            }



            //var test = _obj.ToString();


            //tblOrder ord = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<tblOrder>(obj);
            Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");

            //UNCOMMENT BELOW CODE TO GENERATE EXCEPTION, SO THAT MESSSAGE WILL BE ADDED IN DEAD LETTER QUEUE
            //int i = 0;
            //i = i / Convert.ToInt32(message);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError(ex);
            if (ex.Message == "Input string was not in a correct format.")
            {
                AzureServiceBusMessageResponseModel azureResponse = new AzureServiceBusMessageResponseModel
                {
                    Code = MessageCode.IncorrectDataFormat,
                    Message = ex.Message
                };
                que.SendResponseMessageToServiceBus(azureResponse, OutletId);
            }
            if (ex.Message == "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.")
            {
                AzureServiceBusMessageResponseModel azureResponse = new AzureServiceBusMessageResponseModel
                {
                    Code = MessageCode.IncorrectDataFormat,
                    Message ="Order DateTime is in wrong format.Correct format is dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                };
                que.SendResponseMessageToServiceBus(azureResponse, OutletId);
            }
            await queueClient.AbandonAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
            //var serviceListner = new AzureBusServiceQueListinerController();
            //serviceListner.LogError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please check whether the message in the service bus Explore is consumed.

Comment: Check if your Connection string has enough permissions to receive messages.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your Connection string has enough permissions to receive messages. Appended `TransportType=AmqpWebSockets` to the end of connection string and it worked.

For more details, you could refer to this similar [issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/502).

Answer (score 0):

I have increased Message lock duration on message on Azure portal, this resolved my issue